# Dynamically resolve class to global scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, autoload

I need to save a reference of a class to a hash:

```
@hash['foo'] = bar if bar.is_a?(Class)
```

The above piece of code lives in my `/lib` directory, it is not autoloaded every time, and `bar` is usually an autoloaded class. In order to avoid getting the "A copy of xxx has been removed from the module tree but is still active" error when I `reload!` my code, I am trying to resolve `bar` to the global scope, i.e.: add `::` before the class name (`Baz` is becoming `::Baz`).

I am not sure how I can dynamically perform this **without** converting the class to a string, prepending `::`, and then converting it back to a class.

Comment: The constant is resolved upon assignment. It's like `A = 1; hash['a'] = A; A = 2` – constant and hash are referring to different objects afterwards. Adding `::` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I understand. Then how can I overcome to error mentioned in my question?

Comment: Either by storing the constant's name and using `const_get` / `constantize` (which is what you try to avoid) or by using a proc, e.g. `@hash['foo'] = -> { Baz }` which can be dynamically resolved via `@hash['foo'].call`

Comment: Looks pretty fair. Can you submit it as the answer? I would love to accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning a constant to a hash, the constant is resolved upon assignment: (not hash specific, this is just how constants work)

```
hash = {}
A = 1
hash[:a] = A
#=> 1          # <- 1 is being assigned, not A

A = 2
hash[:a]
#=> 1
```

One way to solve it is to store the constant's name:

```
hash = {}
A = 1
hash[:a] = 'A'
#=> 'A'
```

and to resolve it via [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get) / [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize):

```
A = 2
Object.const_get(hash[:a])
#=> 2
```

This also works for nested constants:

```
hash[:pi] = 'Math::PI'
Object.const_get(hash[:pi])
#=> 3.141592653589793
```

If your object happens to be a named class (or module), you can retrieve its name via [`Module#name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-name):

```
hash[:lazy_enum] = Enumerator::Lazy.name
#=> "Enumerator::Lazy"

Object.const_get(hash[:lazy_enum])
#=> Enumerator::Lazy
```

A different approach is to use a [proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Proc.html) which references the constant in its block:

```
hash = {}
A = 1
hash[:a] = -> { A }
#=> #<Proc:0x00007fc4ba05f510@(irb):10 (lambda)>
```

the constant will be resolved when invoking the block:

```
A = 2
hash[:a].call
#=> 2
```